# Please recommend php xml parser (some 3rd party library)

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Please recommend **php xml parser** library, I can't use default php xml parser lib because it take too much time for parsing my script and apache dies. (no ability to config Timeout option, so I want flush() from time to time to keep it alive)

Comment: If the default XML parser lib times out, any third-party script is likely to time out as well. Why can't you flush() in the default PHP implementation?

Comment: how? all magic is behind xml_parse_into_struct() , filsize is 24 MB

Comment: @ceejayoz Usually a PHP script can't handle a file that big. The solution in these situations is to use an event based parser and keep only the data you need from the XML.

Comment: are you expecting some result to display right after xml parsing completed ?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to need [the  expat parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xml.php). Luckily PHP has this already built in.

In case you're not familiar with it, the expat parser is an event based parser. It does not create a tree from your document (like the DOM and the SimpleXML libraries do), it just parses from start to end and triggers events when it finds certain XML components, like tags and data.

To see an example implementation you can look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_parser_expat.asp) on w3schools.

Comment: unfortunatelly built-in doesn't fit to mine requirements

Comment: @oglyhov Pardon me? Did you try this extension already and did not work? What does *built-in* have to do with anything? There are two types of parsers: tree and event. If you use **any** tree parser the result will probably be the same: your script crashes. You need to use an event parser. What I gave you is exactly that.

Comment: @oglyhov Oh, and by using this parser you'll actually have to use your brain a little... Is this the problem? This parsing model allows both flushing and timeout. But you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: DOM is more preffered than SAX, i need quickfix

Comment: @oglyhov Good luck then... You already have my opinion.

Comment: @oglyhov Sometimes there isn't a "quick fix".